# Invoking the command remotely via http protocol

Tags: java, http

I have Some Commands Which are to be sent to the target node via HTTP protocol. I need to figure out which HTTP verb is used to invoke this command  remotely and the request headers to be set. Can anyone help me out on this?

Comment: Do you really expect anyone to be able to help you with this question as it is? "Some commands" are not simply triggered using one of the existing HTTP methods.

Comment: Your question is very vague, which makes it impossible to give you any useful answer. What exactly do you mean with "commands"? Why do you need to figure out which HTTP verbs and headers you need to use; is there no documentation or information about how to use the services that you need to use?

Answer (score 0):

There are no HTTP verbs which translate to commands.

you need to have an HTTP server on the target node that translates your HTTP requests into shell commands, I have done a google search and found this project https://github.com/msoap/shell2http which might do what you need.

If you need to do your project using java then here is an article about the topic https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/